# Data received from Android Bluetooth socket is getting plotted in the line chart only after socket's termination

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, mpandroidchart

I have recently started working on Android, Kotlin and MPAndroidChart. I am developing an Android application that receives data from a bluetooth server and the data obtained should be plotted in real time using MPAndroidChart.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
package com.example.flowsensor

import ...

class ConnectionActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{
        val TAG = "FlowSensor"
        val APP_NAME = "FlowSensor"
        var myUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66")
        var mBluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
        lateinit var mProgress: ProgressDialog
        lateinit var mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
        var mIsConnected: Boolean = false
        lateinit var mAddress: String
        lateinit var editText:EditText
        lateinit var mChart:LineChart
        var xVal:Int = 0
        var yVal:Int = 0
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection)

        mChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.line_chart)

       receive_button.setOnClickListener{
            ReceiveData()
        }
    }

    //1 parameters missing
    private fun mAddEntry() {
        Log.d(TAG, "yVal : $yVal")
        var mData = mChart.data

        if(mData != null){
            var mDataSet = mData.getDataSetByIndex(0)

            if(mDataSet == null){
                mDataSet = createDataSet()
                mData.addDataSet(mDataSet)
            }

            var mEntry:Entry = Entry( xVal.toFloat(), yVal.toFloat())
            xVal++

            mData.addEntry(mEntry, 0)

            //Notify chart data has changed
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged()

            //Limit no of visible entries
           // mChart.setVisibleXRange(1f, 6f)
            mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6f)

            //Scroll to the last entry
            mChart.moveViewToX(xVal.toFloat())
        }
    }

    //1 parameter missing
    private fun createDataSet(): LineDataSet? {
        var mDataSet = LineDataSet(null, "Data vals")

        //mDataSet.setDrawCubic
        mDataSet.cubicIntensity = 0.2f
        mDataSet.axisDependency = YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT
        mDataSet.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue())
        mDataSet.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue())
        mDataSet.lineWidth = 2f
        mDataSet.circleSize = 4f
        mDataSet.fillAlpha = 65
        mDataSet.fillColor = ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()
        mDataSet.highLightColor = Color.rgb(244, 117, 177)
        mDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.WHITE
        mDataSet.valueTextSize = 10f

        return mDataSet
    }

    private fun ReceiveData() {
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024) // buffer store for the stream
        var bytes: Int // bytes returned from read()
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside ReceiveData()")
        while (true) { // Read from the InputStream
            if(mBluetoothSocket != null)
            {
                try {
                    bytes = mBluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(buffer)
                    val incomingMessage = String(buffer, 0, bytes)
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: $incomingMessage")
                    yVal = incomingMessage.toInt()
                    mAddEntry()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.message)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the [logcat log](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApBA0M-4HrIghAnOfHauecyqAy0I) logged in verbose mode.

App starts in the Main Activity(code not attached here), looks for paired devices then using 
`val intent = Intent(this, ConnectionActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address)
            startActivity(intent)` code, control reaches Connection Activity (code attached above).

App is successfully receiving data from server; verified by observing logcat. In ReceiveData(), I am trying to pass the received data to mAddEntry() which is responsible for drawing the graph. But the problem is, data is plotted only after I terminate the socket, so after Line no 112 in the attached logcat log, all the data is plotted at once (no data loss). I want to plot data in real time, and this is the problem I am facing.

Note: graph plotting has been independently verified by passing dummy data in real-time inside onCreate() in ConnectionActivity class using the timer.scheduleAtFixedRate. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by calling the reciveData() inside the receive_button onClickListner you are executing while loop that will run until Bluetooth socket is connected and it is runing on the MainThread (UIThread) and it will block the UI thread and doesn't let any other ui updateto happen you should execute the reciveData() function on the background and when you want the plot the data in chart you should pass the data in ui thread or call the  mAddEntry() function in ui thread

Comment: I did get the doubt after seeing line no 113 in log but wanted to confirm. Now, I have created a thread for receiveData() and using BroadcastReceiver approach I have fixed the problem. I have couple of questions though,   1)  In my previous code, I was calling mAddEntry() in receiveData() and even though, it  is in Main thread , logically speaking, mAddEntry() should be executed and graph should be plotted. So, why would the UI thread get blocked?  2) Is UI thread part of Main thread or are they same? Any material related to this subject is appreciated. I am just 7 days Androd+ Koltin old.

Comment: hi in android there is single thread named MainThread (or UiThread) wich will handle all the UI related stuff drawing views on screen laying them out and updating them and etc if you do heavy stuff on this thread or in another word if you block this thread (like running infinite while loop) ui cant be updated until the MainThread becomes available and it can do other stuff

Comment: in this kind of situation you should do your processing on other threads by creating a new thread or using frameworks (Rx,AsyncTask,Service,) which they manage the creating the thread and running it and etc because manging thread is a whole other story and when your processing is done and you want to update view you should do that in the MainThread because only main thread is allowed to update the views

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui